# Javascript Inheritance Overriding

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns, prototypal-inheritance

There's a lot of confusing literature on the net about Javascript overriding. But, I haven't found one any that does what I need. I'm trying to enable inheritance and method override, but in a particular way.

Imagine:

```
var A = function(amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
    var _this = this;

    this.method1 = function() {
        some_asynchronous_function(this.amount, function(result) {
            _this.method2(result);
        });
    };
    //The function we want to override!
    this.method2 = function(result) {
        do_stuff(result);
    };
};

var B = function(amount) {
    this.method2 = function(result) {
        do_different_stuff(result);
    };
    A.call(this, amount);
};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

My goal is to be able to keep everything from the `A` class except for the the `this.method2`. However, when I instantiate `B` in my code and call `B.method1`, it executes the `method2` from `A`. Is there a way to mix and match what I keep in with Javascript?

Comment: Of course it does. You've defined those methods as instance attributes that get defined in the constructor and you're calling A's constructor after you defined this.method2 so the `A.call(this, amount)` will overwrite what you have just before it.

Comment: @PSkocik Are you saying all I need to do is define the overridden method after I `A.call(this, amount)`?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with prototypal inheritance. You're A's prototype  property is empty. You should  move the method definitions to prototypes, though, so they can get reused and won't need to be defined in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates the essence of your problem:

```
var A = function() {
    this.m1 = function(){ console.log('hi from m1 from A');  };
    this.m2 = function(){ console.log('hi from m2 from A');  };
};

var B = function() {
    this.m2 = function(){ console.log('hi from m2 from B');  };
    A.call(this); //try swapping this with the previous line
};
(new B()).m2();
```

You're defining methods as instance attributes, in the constructor.
Since you're making the `A` constructor run after the `m2` definition and since the constructor has its own `m2` definition, it'll override the definition before it.

No prototypes are in effect here.

You should however be using prototypes for this.
If you define those methods as instance properties, they'll be redefined for each instance individually with each `new`.

If you move those method definitions to the prototype, the code will get reused:

```
var A = function() {

};
A.prototype.m1 = function(){ console.log('hi from m1 from A');  };
A.prototype.m2 = function(){ console.log('hi from m2 from A');  };

var B = function() {
    A.call(this); 
};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.m2 = function(){ console.log('hi from m2 from B');  };

(new B()).m2();
(new B()).m1();
```

After that, prototypal inheritance is really simple:

- instance methods/attributes override they're prototypal ancestors
- attributes found in the prototype override attributes that would be found in the prototype's prototype (and so on)
- all writes go to the instance (`instance.attr` = 42 won't overwrite attr in a prototype but rather will create a new attr property on `instance`)

Answer (score 0):

You need prototypal inheritance, something like this:

```
var A = function (){
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};
A.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    amount: null,
    init: function (amount){
        this.amount = amount;
    },
    method1: function() {
        some_asynchronous_function(this.amount, this.method2.bind(this));
    },
    method2: function(result) {
        do_stuff(result);
    };
});

var B = function (){
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {
    method2: function(result) {
        do_different_stuff(result);
    }
});
```

*Note: the Object.create does not have a second param in every environment.*

Most of the js frameworks support inheritance more or less, pick one. If you want to create your own, then I have implemented an extend function [here](https://github.com/inf3rno/dataflower/blob/master/core.js#L102), maybe you can use some of the ideas.

An alternative to use a different class for method2, if your A class has too many lines (e.g. more than 50), or methods (more than 10) or it violates the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Or simply because [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). But I guess these things do not really matter by you.